# How to feed Imported Namespaces into CompileAssemblyFromSource

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to load a VB source file into memory.  However, the VB file assumes that Project it is associated to has some global "Imported Namespaces" defined at the project level.  This VB feature allows individual files to omit the Imports statement (Using in C#) on every single file.

```
    Dim sourceCode As String = ""
    'sourceCode &= "Imports System.Data" & vbNewLine
    sourceCode &= "Class Foo" & vbNewLine
    sourceCode &= "Sub Print()" & vbNewLine
    sourceCode &= "Dim dtbl As DataTable" & vbNewLine
    sourceCode &= "System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello, world!"")" & vbNewLine
    sourceCode &= "End Sub" & vbNewLine
    sourceCode &= "End Class" & vbNewLine

    Dim compiler As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider

    Dim params As New Compiler.CompilerParameters
    params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
    params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll")
    params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll")
    params.GenerateInMemory = True
    params.GenerateExecutable = False

    Dim results As Compiler.CompilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, sourceCode)

    If results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        For Each compileError In results.Errors
            Console.WriteLine(compileError.ToString)
        Next
        Return
    End If

    Dim assembly = results.CompiledAssembly
```

Line 2 is commented out.  If I uncomment this and add the Imports statement the code works fine.  It also works fine if I change "Dim dtbl As DataTable" to "Dim dtbl As System.Data.DataTable".

Instead of uncommenting that line of code, is there a way to feed this Imports statement into the compiler or params as if it was a global project level Imported Namespace?

I could just add this Imports statement to the top of each file I read in.  But if it is already there then I get an error that the Imports statement is duplicate.  I could do some Regex checking to see if the Imports statement is already there, but I'd like to leverage the System.CodeDom framework as much as possible.

Comment: When you compile an arbitrary vb.net source code file then the compiler failing to compile it is the expected outcome.  Don't try to build an AI program to guess what's wrong and correct it, just tell the user about the errors generated by the compiler.  Like VS does.

Comment: Thanks.  It isn't exactly **arbitrary** vb.net source code through.  I'm assuming that they'll importing code from an older version of my code generator.  The older version of the code generator relied on global Imports, but new versions explicitly the Imports in each file.  My program needs to successfully import both old and new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, no answers :(  I guess the framework doesn't do what I'd like to do.  Here is my hacky solution using Regex to inject the Imports statement.

```
sourceCode = AddImportsIfNeeded(sourceCode, "System.Data")


Private Function AddImportsIfNeeded(ByVal sourceCode As String, ByVal namespaceToImport As String) As String

    If Not Regex.IsMatch(sourceCode, "^\s*Imports\s+" & Regex.Escape(namespaceToImport) & "\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline) Then
        Return "Imports " & namespaceToImport & vbNewLine & sourceCode
    End If
    Return sourceCode

End Function
```

Note that this won't work if the file contains Option statements (like Option Strict On).  The Imports statements must go below the Option statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can import namespaces using the `CompilerOptions` property of the `CompilerParameters` class.  Add this line to your example, and the compiler will no longer generate a compiler error:

```
params.CompilerOptions = "/import:System.Data"
```