# Globally importing VB.Net namespaces

Tags: c#, vb.net, codedom, vbcodeprovider

I've got a C# program this is attempting to dynamically compile some VB.Net code.

```
var vbc = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> 
           { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] {"mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll", 
    "System.Data.dll", "System.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"},
    @"MyFile.exe", false)
{
    GenerateInMemory = false,
    GenerateExecutable = true
};

CompilerResults results = vbc.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, "file1.vb", "file2.vb", 
            "file3.vb", "file4.vb");
```

It's working, but with errors. The problem is, in a real Visual Basic project, by default, the following namespaces are automatically imported:

```
System
System.Collections
System.Collections.Generic
System.Data
System.Diagnostics
System.Linq
System.Xml.Linq
System.Threading.Tasks
Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

You can verify this yourself by going to create a new Visual Basic project, then looking at the properties of the project and clicking References. You will see that the above listed namespaces are automatically imported.

My question is, how do I globally auto import these namespaces and pass it into `VBCodeProvider` so it will automatically import these when it tries to compile?

I found a similar question to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718110/how-to-feed-imported-namespaces-into-compileassemblyfromsource), however, no answers have been provided except by the OP, who is doing something "hacky", which I prefer not to do.

Comment: These aren't auto imported, just add them to the begining of the code as normal Imports.

Comment: @Gusman - The problem is, I cannot modify the source code files. They need to remain in tact.

Comment: Then instead of CompileAssemblyFromFile use CompileAssemblyFromSource, it will expect an array of strings with the code, you can then add anything what you want to those strings without modifying the original files.